# How do I know from the Linux command line what kind of processor I have?

Tags: command-line-interface, central-processing-unit

How can I tell from the Linux command line what kind of processor my machine has?  E.g. AMD Opteron or Intel Core 2 Duo.

uname -a just tells me it's x86_64 but that isn't enough information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dmidecode
```

or preferably

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

dmidecode will give you a lot more info than just what processor, thou /proc/cpuinfo provides more info about the processor itself